# Clean restore from PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want to restore a database from backup and rewrite all data that is there with backup data.

My current command is like this:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -d dbName -v autobackup_file.dmp
```

How to restore and rewrite all data?
I've seen an option `-c`; is that the correct way?
And where should I put it in my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-c` can be anywhere, e.g. immediately after `pg_restore`.

It will `DROP` all restored objects before restoring them, but it will not drop any objects that are *not* in the dump.

To drop and recreate the whole database so you get a clean copy, you can use `-C -c`.